# predicate logic formula truth models

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Show that the following set of formulas is consistent. (Do it by constructing a model where both formulas are true.)

$\forall x (S(x) \to Q(x))$

$\exists x (Q(x) \land \lnot S(x))$

I know the answer is pretty simple ,but for the life of me I am hitting a blank and can't find a situation where both formulas are true. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know it's predicates of arity 1 and contains no free variables i.e they are sentences.

Comment: If every $S$ is a $Q$, in order to satisfy the second formula we have to find two classes $S$ and $Q$ such that $S$ is a **proper** subset of $Q$: in that way, we can find an element of $Q$ that is **not** an $S$.

Comment: "Every male is human" and "There is (at least) one human that is not a male".

Comment: Is this then the same as all animals that fly are birds but not all birds can fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ and $Q$ are unary predicates, i.e. realized as subsets of the domain of a model. As $\forall x(S(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ ought to be true, we have that the realization of $S$ has to be *subset* of $Q$.

However, $\exists x(Q(x)\land\neg S(x))$ requires one element(at least) in the domain s.t. it is in the realization of $Q$ but not in the one of $S$. Thus $S$ has to be a *proper* *subset*.

---

By the means of an example. I assume that your signature is just $(S,Q)$:

Consider the model $$\mathfrak{M}=(\mathbb{Z},S_\mathbb{Z},Q_\mathbb{Z})$$ where $S_\mathbb{Z}=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid x>0\}$ and $Q_\mathbb{Z}=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}\mid x\geq0\}$.

Then, $\mathfrak{M}\models\forall x(S(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$, as for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $S_\mathbb{Z}(x)$, i.e. $x>0$, then $x\geq 0$, i.e. $Q_\mathbb{Z}(x)$.

However, $\mathfrak{M}\models\exists x(Q(x)\land\neg S(x))$, as for $x=0\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have $x\geq 0$, i.e. $Q_\mathbb{Z}(x)$ but $x\not >0$, i.e. not $S_\mathbb{Z}(x)$.

Comment: That would satisfy 1 model. But the question asked for 2 models. My apologies i'm still new to first order logic.

Comment: @KazyKamakaze What do you mean with "1 model" ? Do you want two examples? Because this is one model satisfying both formulas simultaneously.

Comment: No worries I read thru the last bit too quickly . My apologies you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S(x)$ be $x$ goes in rain without an umbrella, and $Q(x)$ be $x$ gets  wet.

Then $S(x)\implies Q(x)$ but there is someone who gets wet without going in rain.